# Erro ao fazer deploy no Wildfly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou recebendo um erro ao tentar fazer *deploy* da minha aplicação no Wildfly 8:

> Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011445: Failed to get adapter for persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'

Meu persistence.xml :

```
<persistence-unit name="budget-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/budget-ds</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate"/>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.adapterModule" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Estou usando MySQL 5.5, Hibernate 4.1 e Wildfly 8.

Alguém sabe a causa do erro, e como resolvê-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` está disponível a partir da versão 4.3 do Hibernate.

Antes disso, o *provider* correto é:

```xml
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Veja a [documentação aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UpdateyourPersistence.xmlforHibernate4.3.0).

---

### Update

Conforme relatou o OP, a questão foi resolvida removendo a linha:

```xml
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.adapterModule" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4"/>
```

Segundo a documentação sobre as [propriedades do módulo JPA do Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23035974#JPAReferenceGuide-Persistenceunitproperties), a propriedade `jboss.as.jpa.adapterModule` define quais classes de integração o servidor de aplicação deve usar para trabalhar com o *persistent provider* (o Hibernate, neste caso).

No entanto, se essa propriedade for adicionada, o Wildfly parece não conseguir encontrar a implementação do Hibernate (vide erro na pergunta).

Isso provavelmente é um *bug* relacionado ao fato de você usar o Hibernate da sua aplicação e não o que vêm embutido com o servidor, como descrito na documentação [*Native Hibernate Usage*](https://docs.jboss.org/author/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23035974#JPAReferenceGuide-NativeHibernateuse). Removendo a propriedade, o servidor consegue usar o Hibernate da aplicação.

Comment: acabou que confundi.. a versão do meu hibernate é a: **4.3.1.Final**

Comment: @BlackSheep O problema pode ser causado porque o Wildfly contém um módulo com uma versão do Hibernate mais antiga, que está tendo precedência sobre a versão na sua lib. Verifique nos diretórios do wildfly qual a versão do Hibernate que vem com ele.

Comment: no diretório 
/opt/servidores/wildfly-8.0.0.CR1/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main
tem a versão **hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final**

Comment: @BlackSheep Fiz uma pesquisa por "Failed to get adapter for persistence provider" e não aparece nada relevante. Sem a aplicação em mãos para fuçar está difícil ajudar. Eu começaria revisando essas propriedades do Hibernate. Olhe [este link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-Persistenceunitproperties). Tente remover essas propriedades `jboss.jpa.*`. Tente também adicionar `jboss.as.jpa.managed` com valor `false`.

Comment: mudei meu persitence.XML, tirei essa linha aqui:
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.adapterModule" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4"/>

aí funcionou, de qualquer forma aí valeu pela tentativa!!!

Comment: @BlackSheep Legal. Eu não tinha como testar, mas imaginei que mexendo nessas propriedades poderia resultar em alguma coisa, por isso coloquei o último comentário sobre remover as propriedades `jboss.as.jpa.*` (havia escrito errado). De qualquer forma, atualizei a resposta para que alguém que encontre essa pergunta possa obter ajuda mais facilmente.